# How do I display a file for download in Angular once the file is processed in Node/Express backend and ready for the user?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, socket.io

With this particular use case below is the workflow.

1. User uploads a .csv file (100+MB) using Angular 5 frontend web page. (works)
2. This file is uploaded to /uploads/user/input folder using nodejs/express (multer) middleware.(works)
3. Chokidar watches this /uploads/user/input/ folder for any .csv uploads once the watcher identifies a file addition, it spawns child_process to execute a mongoimport and then execute a python script.(works)
4. The python script does necessary processing and creates an output file for the user and drops it in the /user/output folder.(works)

Everything until here works perfectly fine.

What I want to do now once the output file is ready I want to display that file link for download back in the angular component that uploaded the input file. How do I go about doing that? So I came across socket.io and here is what I have done so far.

I have a chokidar watcher on for a file pattern on the output directory.

```
const pattern11 = './api/uploads/updateusername/output/*.dat';
const watcher11 = chokidar.watch(pattern11);
```

Once the watcher catches the filepath added I am trying to emit an event FileReady. Snippets of the server code below.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();
var multer = require('multer');
var chokidar = require('chokidar');
const server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('User connected');
});

watcher11
  .on('add', path => {
                        console.log(`File ${path} has been added`);
                        io.emit('FileReady', path);
                    });

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on localhost:${port}`));
```

On the Angular client side of things I have a socketio service that I am hoping will be able to catch the socket emits from the server.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class SocketioService {

  private socket;
  filepath = '';

  constructor() { }

  connect(){
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

    let observable = new Observable(observer => {
        this.socket.on('FileReady', (data) => {
          console.log("Received message from Websocket Server");
          this.filepath = data;
          observer.next(data);
        }).subscribe();
    });
  }
}
```

I was hoping when the io emit 'FileReady' is executed on the server my service would be able to get the data.

In the Angular component I inject this service into the constructor and call connect(). Code below.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private fileService: FileService, private socketioService: SocketioService) {
    this.files = [];
    this.uploadInput = new EventEmitter<UploadInput>();
    this.humanizeBytes = humanizeBytes;
    this.socketioService.connect();
  }
```

One thing to keep in mind.

The time span between the initial post that uploads the file and the output file being available could be up to 15 mins. Until then I am planning to show the user in Angular - "File is being processed message". Once the file is available I will update the component with the file download link.

Is there a way to do this or should I not design the solution in the aforementioned way.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you at least show you tried? see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @StephenRauch sure, I removed the python tag.

Comment: One simplest approach would be implementing client polling, where client frequently poll for status of specific operation ID returned by the upload endpoint.